# Calculating total fluorescence based on thin slices in a slab

Tags: fluorescence

I am modeling an acid-base reaction that includes a fluorescence indicator. My simple model is a slab of acid next to a slab of base and so on. These slabs are very thin, typically less than 10 microns and are assumed to be laminar such that diffusion is the only method of mass transport. At the interface of acid and base the reaction occurs and the pH is 10^-7 (which is shown as zero on the attached figure).

The attached figure shows an example of the concentration gradients of acid and base at some time t. Because of symmetry only a half slab of acid is shown next to a half slab of base. I want to calculate the total fluorescence emitted from both half slabs together. With regards to the concentrations on the figure, for the acid slab the concentration is the hydrogen ion concentration.  For the base slab the concentration is the hydroxyl ion concentration. I have an equation which gives me the fluorescence as a function of pH.

So the way I have been calculating the fluorescence is to get the pH for each slice shown in the figure and assume that the pH is constant for that slice (of course as the slice thickness is decreased this becomes a better assumption). Then the fluorescence is calculated for each slice based on the known pH and the equation.

Now comes my question: If I want to calculate the total fluorescence for both slabs, can I just simply add up the fluorescence from each slice in the acid slab and base slab? In other words, the total fluorescence emitted from both slabs together is the sum of the individual fluorescence for each slice. Is this the correct methodology?

[image]

Comment: Is the fluorescent emitter the same in both acidic and basic solutions ? Why do you think the neutral mixture is not fluorescent ?

Comment: Yes, I am using umbelliferone in both the acid and base and the concentrations are the same, so there is no diffusion gradient for the umbelliferone.  I did not mean to mislead regarding the pH7.  A pH of 7 is definitely fluorescent.  I was just showing the concentration gradients and that bit of information is more important for the analytical model than for my question.  Sorry to confuse and thanks for bringing up the point about possible diffusion of the umbelliferone.  Any thoughts on my question regarding adding up the slice fluorescences to get the total for both half slabs?

Comment: What is the meaning of the two curves  c(x,t) going to zero in the middle of the diagram ? Are the curves theoretical or experimental ? Why are there no numerical values on the Ox axis ? Why is the time not mentioned ?

Comment: You say you have fluorescence yield vs pH, (f(pH) )so the total will be weighted according to this, so you have f(pH)Conc(acid)+f(pH)Conc(base) = total  fluorescence so you seem not to have enough information, one measurement but two values you need. But I'm not clear about what you are actually doing

Comment: The figure is just meant to provide an idea of the concentration profiles at a specific time. Where the curves go to zero is the reaction plan of acid and base.  The mathematical model assumes that acid and base cannot coexist and sets this value as zero.  However, as mentioned above, the value is actually 10-7, which for all practical purposes is zero and does not affect any model calculation determining the pH of the curves. The curves are theoretical.  On the x axis the values can be listed as -L on the left side and +L on the right side. L is the half slab thickness.

Comment: @porphyrin:  Let me make sure I understand what you are saying.  You are saying that I just add the calculated fluorescence value for the base slab to the calculated fluorescence value for the acid slab.  If so, that is what I have been doing.   However, in each slab the pH is not constant; hence the slices for each slab. The pH/fluorescence equation that I have is based on a thickness, sm.   I am calculating the pH and then fluorescence for each slice where it is assumed that these values are constant within the thin slice.  Comment continues..........

Comment: The pH for a slice is calculated from Fick's diffusion model (attached diagram shows the concentration profiles (or alternatively, pH profiles) at a specific time, t). Then the equation is used to get the fluorescence at that pH.  The equation, however, provides a fluorescence value for a known thickness, sm. So to get the fluorescence for the slice, multiply the calculated fluorescence by the slice thickness, dx, divided by the thickness, sm.  The foregoing is accomplished for all slices in both half slabs.  Comment continues below.....

Comment: Finally, all of the slice fluorescences are summed to get the total fluorescence for the two half slabs, which is a thickness of 2L (see my previous comment on half slab thickness).  Please let me know if this is not what you mean.

Comment: Your method seems fine, as long as your excitation light source is strong enough in intensity.  You don't want the light absorption by any of your slices to significantly affect the excitation intensity in the layer below.  Also, you might want to make sure that the absorbance of your "slices" for the _emitted_ light is negligible too.  If both of these assumptions are met, then each slice really is independent of the adjacent ones, and you can probably add up all the fluorescence to get the total

Comment: @Curt F.  The procedure I outlined above is for a specific time.  My simulation actually runs for about a thousand iterations or so, so from time, t = 0 to t = tfinal.  My simulated total fluorescence as a function of time profile is then compared to the experimental one.  I guess values of the slab thickness until the profiles match.  For about 25% of my data, no correction value is needed in order to get the profiles to match (at a specific value of L). However, for the other 75%, the simulation seems to understimate the fluorescence when compared to the experimental fluorescence.

Comment: But I find that if I multiply all of the simulated fluorescence values (values at each time step) by a single constant value, then the profiles will match reasonably well.  So a single correction factor applied to the entire simulation fluorescence curve will result in it matching the experimental curve. I have been puzzled by why this is the case.  Perhaps it is due to the cautions that you outline in your post.  Unfortunately, I don't feel that I have a full understanding of the issues that you bring up.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be interested in monitoring pH gradients across the glass slab based on diffusion of an acid and base by monitoring the variation in fluorescence intensity or emission maximum shifts. Before you proceed further on this fancy experiment you will have to establish certain fluorescence facts. Hence control experiments are extremely necessary.
A quick survey on Google Scholar will show that umbelliferone emission is pH dependent. I am sure you will have access to a good quality spectrofluorometer. Make sure you collect emission spectrum at the pH range of interest with *identical* concentrations of the dye in various pH solutions. By identical concentration of the dye in each pH solution, I mean prepare dye solutions as accurately as analytically possible. One could be prepare a stock solution of the dye and perhaps weigh the volume transferred just to be very accurate in each pH solution.

Once you collect emission spectra (fixed excitation), the emission maxima will/might change. The key observation here is that *do emission intensities also change or not as a function of pH?*

When the fluorescence intensity and emission are changing, it implies that we are not dealing with identical species of the dye, thus different "species" have different fluorescence quantum yields. It is then perhaps not kosher to add up fluorescence intensities. Alternatively, you might try even a fancier experiment and measure quantum yields as a function of pH.

Of course, the measuring instrument is oblivious to these things, it is just counting photons from the region you are collecting light from. In short, the experiment is not trivial and the deeper we explore, the more problems will be exposed. For example, is the detector uniformly sensitive to all the wavelengths of your interest or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't clear that the medium here is liquid. To provide more information, I am impinging an acid sheet of liquid with a base sheet of liquid and watching the fluorescence change within the combined sheet that is produced.  I have already shown that within the combined sheet, the liquid flows along radial lines (i.e. there is no crossover of liquid from one radial line to the next) and thus the attached diagram is applicable to actual conditions.  However as noted above, the diagram only shows one time. I should have attached a diagram showing profiles at different times.